# Why does the width change when i change text size?

Tags: html, css

See this page i'm currently working on.
http://lacrosselaundry.com/lacrosseLaundry/contact.php

If i change the font-size for 6 from 14px to 18px it moves the form to the right. Why is that?

I want the form to be all the way over to the right like when the h6 font is 18px, except i want the h6 font to be 14 px. How do I fix this and why is it happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about setting element sizes? Works for me in firebug.

```
#main {
    width: 100%;
}
.clearLeft {
    width: 300px;
}
```

As for reasons, `.rightDiv` moves (despite having `align: right`) because parent container (`#main`) width increase. I.e., you increase font size and container stretches to accomodate changes. Normally divs take up all available width, but having `float: left` overrides that.

Comment: I didn't need to specifically set a width to clearLeft, just setting the #main width to 100% worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set the width of `#main` to 100%, so the `#main .rigthDiv` element would truly float to the right.